# Adding a view on perspective in particular folder

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-3.6

In my Eclipse RCP application I have four views A, B, C, D. I want to display only A, B, C view at application start-up, and D view to be displayed when user click on button.[image: On start-up Application will look like this]

I am adding a view dynamically

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().showView("D_ViewID",null, IWorkbenchPage.VIEW_ACTIVATE);
```

this view is added at the bottom but I want this D view adjacent to B_View in such a way
[image]

my perspective code is here:

```
@Override
public void createInitialLayout(IPageLayout layout) {

    String editor = layout.getEditorArea();
    layout.setEditorAreaVisible(false); 

    IFolderLayout top=layout.createFolder("view",IPageLayout.TOP , 0.80f, editor);
    top.addView(B.ID);

    layout.addView(A.ID, IPageLayout.LEFT, 0.20f, BrowserView.B);           
    layout.addView(c.ID, IPageLayout.BOTTOM, 0.20f,editor); 
}
```

Comment: may be `org.eclipse.ui.actionSets` extension point would help you here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to [add a placeholder](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/IPageLayout.html#addPlaceholder%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20float,%20java.lang.String%29) to the perspective, just like you added your already visible views. If you look at the top of the [IPageLayout documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/IPageLayout.html), there is an example adding the bookmarks view as placeholder.